# Rails 3 and vlad the deployer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, vlad-deployer

i couldn't find anywhere if vlad it's compatible with Rails 3, but i tried to deploy a new rails 3 app that we're developing and always returns the same error:

```
Error loading vlad: no such file to load -- vladrake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'vlad:init_setup:production'
```

I'm using ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i686-darwin9.8.0]

And rails 3.0.1 and i testit with vlad 2.0.0 and vlad 2.1.0

In the Rakefile i have this:

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
require 'rake'

begin
 require 'rubygems'
 require 'vlad'
 Vlad.load :scm => :git, :app => :passenger
rescue LoadError => e
 $stderr << "Error loading vlad: #{e}"
end
```

If anyone has an idea where to look at it in order to fixit or maybe tell me if vlad it's rails 3 ready?

Thanks in advance for your time

Cavi

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already figured this out, but do you have vlad included in your Gemfile? You probably want to add:

```
group :development do
  gem 'vlad-git'
  gem 'vlad'
end
```

Then run bundle.